# Batchfile command using C++

Tags: c++, batch-file

I have to run the below batch file command using `system()` in C++. However, I was unable to get the command right.

How do I write the below command with proper syntax in C++?

```
CALL install\setup.exe /s /v" /qn "KEY=0000-0000-0000-0000-0000" SHORTCUT=0 INSTALLDIR=\"C:\\Program Files\\Install\\Setup\" /l+*v "%SYSTEMROOT%\Setup.log""
```

Below is my c++ code.

```
int main()
{
    system("\"install\setup.exe\" /s /v /qn KEY=0000-0000-0000-0000-0000 SHORTCUT=0     INSTALLDIR=\ C:\\Program Files\\Install\\Setup\ /l+*v %SYSTEMROOT%\\Setup.log");      
    system("\"C:\\Program Files\\install\\Setup\\setup.exe\" no");   
    system("\"C:\\Program Files\\install\\Setup\\setup.exe\" adder add -y Administrator");    
    system("\"C:\\Program Files\\install\\Setup\\setup.exe\" adder add -y user1");    
    system("\"C:\\Program Files\\install\\Setup\\setup.exe\" adder add -t Device run.exe");    
}
```

Comment: you have to post the code in your question. not as comment. you can do this by editing your question

Comment: Take a look at CreateProcess http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape the `\` characters, just like you did with `"`.
This effectively means you'll need to **double** them, ending up with something horrendous like:

```
system("\"install\\setup.exe\" ... INSTALLDIR=\\\"C:\\\\Program Files\\\\Inst...
```

I'd suggest you start off with only a few parameters, and as you check that it is working, progressively add the rest of them. It will make it easier to debug when you miss a `\`.